# Get iOS device logs from app programatically

Tags: ios, swift, logging

I need to read the console logs from inside of the app, the idea is to use it in internal environment to help users report bugs to us with an internal library that comes bundled inside of the app.

How can I get the log in swift?

*CLARIFICATION:* I dont want to see the iOS logs from device in my computer, I need to get them programatically from inside of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out logging libraries like CocoaLumberjack[1]? It provides file logger (which you can configure to fit your needs: file limit, size limit, rolling, etc), then you can send such file to the server if needed.

[1] - https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack

Comment: But what about logs from third-party services? that part of the logs.